# Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL) - hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Grails and experiencing a weird behavior of hibernate.

Having such a method in the service:

```
def delete(object) {
  def parent = object.parent
  if (parent) {
    object.parent = null
    parent.removeFromX(object)
    parent.save()
  }
  object.delete(flush: true)
}
```

If the `.save()` is triggered and then the `.delete(flush: true)`, I get an error:

`Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.`

The weird part is that if the `.save()` is not triggered (parent is `null`), the delete is working fine - it would mean that calling `.save()` before, marks somehow the transacation as read-only. Is it possible?

The project is using OSIV, if it might help you.

Full stack trace from logs:

```
Stacktrace follows:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1175)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$25.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:839)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:837)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:833)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOperations$delete.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport$_addBasicPersistenceMethods_closure78.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:847)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:307)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at org.pih.warehouse.core.LocationService.deleteLocation(LocationService.groovy:716)
        at org.pih.warehouse.core.LocationService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$366d1ea5.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at org.pih.warehouse.core.LocationService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7d8a27ff.deleteLocation(<generated>)
        at org.pih.warehouse.core.LocationService$deleteLocation.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.pih.warehouse.core.LocationController$_closure6.doCall(LocationController.groovy:162)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at org.pih.warehouse.core.LocationController$_closure6.doCall(LocationController.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:277)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:368)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:232)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:73)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
```

I can confirm, after debugging and looking at flushMode before and after `save()` is called, before save, the `flushMode` is `AUTO`, but after calling save it becomes: `MANUAL`:
[image]

```
public void setFlushMode(FlushMode flushMode) {
        this.errorIfClosed();
        this.checkTransactionSynchStatus();
        if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
            log.trace("setting flush mode to: " + flushMode);
        }

        this.flushMode = flushMode;
    }
```

The `FlushMode.MANUAL` seems to be set here:
[image]

Comment: I expect you're wrong to blame Hibernate here. The problem looks to be caused by something in your usage of Grails or Spring. (Note that there's no Hibernate code in that stack trace.)

Comment: what would you suggest to check? It's weird that after `.save()` operation, the flushMode is changed to `MANUAL`.

Comment: Well, I mean, why don't you just put a breakpoint in `SessionImpl.setHibernateFlushMode()` and see who calls it?

Comment: The method is just like this, so I don't know how I could check who calls it. I am only able to see actual flushMode that is being passed to this method
(I pasted the method in the main comment above, because pasting it here makes it ugly)

Comment: Your debugger will also show the stack. (The list of stack frames of calling methods.)

Comment: I've probably found where it is set, but what is weird is that on Friday it was throwing this error and today it doesn't.... it works fine, anyway, I've pasted the screenshot at the bottom of the post again - it's `validate()` method from `HibernateDomainClassValidator`.

Comment: I mean, I have no idea what that class is. There's no class with that name in Hibernate Validator (nor in Hibernate ORM), so it's probably something from one of the other libraries you're using (as I suggested above).